# Python, how to set constants in init of parent class?

Tags: python

I want to set some constants as members of a class and I feel this is the wrong way to do it:

```
class Unit:                
    def __init__(self, SYMBOL=None, RATIO_TO_METER=None):                                                    
        self._symbol = SYMBOL                         
        self._ratio_to_meter = RATIO_TO_METER         

    def __repr__(self):    
        return self._symbol                           


class Inch(Unit):          
    SYMBOL = 'in'          
    RATIO_TO_METER = 0.0254                           


class Metre(Unit):         
    SYMBOL = 'm'           
    RATIO_TO_METER = 1     


class Yard(Unit):          
    SYMBOL = 'yd'          
    RATIO_TO_METER = 0.9144
```

For instance the `__repr__` method returns None. It seems to execute when `Unit` instantiates and not when I would like to, namely when `self._symbol` has received a value.

I could make it work by having an `__init__` method in each child class but that would not be DRY.
What is the right to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Why not get `__repr__` to just return `self.SYMBOL`?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. As pointed by Martijn, the whole `__init__` is useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already set class attributes, there is no need to pass those into `__init__`. Just use the class attributes directly:

```
class Unit:                
    SYMBOL = None
    RATIO_TO_METER = None

    def __repr__(self):    
        return self.SYMBOL                           


class Inch(Unit):          
    SYMBOL = 'in'          
    RATIO_TO_METER = 0.0254                           


class Metre(Unit):         
    SYMBOL = 'm'           
    RATIO_TO_METER = 1     


class Yard(Unit):          
    SYMBOL = 'yd'          
    RATIO_TO_METER = 0.9144
```

There is little point in setting instance attributes; you already have direct access to the class attributes.